# Informatica PC: how do I make a decision in the flow upon scalar query result?

Tags: variables, persistent, informatica-powercenter

I'm struggling with what seems like the simplest thing there is: assigning a value to a mapping variable that I later on use in my flow to make a decision upon... With my MS SSIS background this is a 10 seconds task, however in Informatica PowerCenter, it is taking me hours...

So I have a mapping variable $$V_FF and a workflow variable $$V_FF. At first the names were different but while trying things out, I changed that. But that shouldn't matter, right?

In a mapping, I have a view as a source that returns -1, 0 or 1. The mapping variable aggregate function is set to MIN.

In the session that I have created for this mapping, I have a post-session assignment between the wf variable and the mapping variable. 
In this mapping I use setvariable function in an Extrans block.

Every time I run the wf, I see in the log that it uses a persistent value instead of assigning a new value everytime the flow is running...

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you have set the aggregation type for the variable to MIN, it will use the minimum of the stored and new value you are setting using setVariable function. So, if the new value is greater than the stored value, it will not change the persistent value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I managed to accomplish what I wanted back then. There might be a better way, but this solution is easy to maintain and easy to understand.

1. Create a variable in your workflow, lets say $$FailureFlag with type integer.
2. Create a view in your DB that returns 1 row with a integer value between 0 and x, where x is a positive integer value.
3. Create a mapping with the view that we just created as the source and use a dummy table as destination.
4. In this mapping you also create a variable, lets say $$MYVAR, with type integer and aggregation "Count". In an "Expression Transformation" I assign the result of the view, column FF, to this variable $$MYVAR by using SETVARIABLE($$MYVAR,FF).
5. From this mapping, create a session in your workflow. In the Components tab, in the "Postsession_success_variable_mapping" section, add a row and link workflow variable $$FailureFlag with session variable $$MYVAR.
6. Add a Decision component right after the session you just created, and test the content of your workflow variable, for example $$V_FAILURE_FLAG_IMX = 1.
7. Connect your decision then with your destination and add a test clause for example:
   "$MyDecision.Condition = true AND $MyDecision.PrevTaskStatus = succeeded"

Voila, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the variables here work in a bit different way indeed. So it would be easier to come up with a good answer or you'd explain the whole scenario: what are you using the variable for?

Anyway, the variable values are persisted in repository and reused, as you've noticed. For your scenario you could add an Assignment Task to the Workflow before your Session. Set some low value (eg. -1 if you expect your variable to have some positive value after the Mapping run) and use PreSession Variable Assignment to pass the value to the Mapping. This will override the use of persisted repository value. If course in this case you will need to use Max aggregation.